# How to request to move a question to programmers.SE?

Tags: support, migration, close-reasons

When I click the Migrate option in the close vote (in off topic), it lists a few sites. To be exact, it lists Meta (this), SuperUser, TeX.SE, DBA.SE and sharepoint.SE. There's not an option for programmers.SE. How do you request a question to be moved to programmers.SE?

Answer (score 0):

Flag it as "it needs ♦ moderator attention -> other" and leave a note for the moderators explaining where you want the question to be migrated and why.